# MySql Workbench access error on adding items but not on creating tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an issue for adding items to a table in MySql.

Situation:

I have a sql script which is a file, locally located, it has following information:

```
CREATE TABLE Regions (
    RegionID smallint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    CountryID smallint NOT NULL ,
    Region varchar (45) NOT NULL ,
    Code varchar (8) NOT NULL ,
    ADM1Code char (4) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(RegionID)
    );

LOAD DATA INFILE 'Regions.txt' INTO TABLE Regions
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

In the MySQL workbench I open that sql file, and I click execute, the table is created, but for populating the table I get an error:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Cities.txt' INTO TABLE Cities FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES    
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

And I really don't understand why ... is this issue with mysql or something wrong with my file ...?

Another question is, where that scripts tries to retrieve the files? I think he might not find the correct location, although even when i tried to give full path to those txt files with data, i still got the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this problem related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570668/mysql-workbench-load-data-local-infile-error ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of SHOW GRANTS;

(you don't have to show any further than ON - we don't need to see your username or host etc)

Comment: @Paul: you should formulate this question as comment, not as answer.

Comment: Yeah @Mike I would but I can't see the comments button on the original post

Comment: @Paul, there's no button but a link "add comment", right above "start a bounty".

Answer (score 0):

Your access denied problem could be because of the permissions on your database for your account but I suspect that it is because the query browser is not using the database your account has permission for.
'%' in the above is not the database you hoped for.

Insert a `use [database]` statement at the top of your script.

The query browser in the workbench does not seem to infer the default database in the way that I would expect and I think this is causing your problem. I often seem to have to insert a use statement to run from within the workbench's query browser.